# firestore order by descending breaks when using startAfter

Tags: reactjs, redux, google-cloud-firestore, pagination, infinite-scroll

I have a function here that is being used to fetch all the documents in a collection.
The information returned is paginated and will only return the next documents when the user scrolls down the page.

```
export function fetchScreamsFromFirestore(limit, lastDocSnapshot = null) {
  let screamsRef = db
    .collection('screams')
    .orderBy('createdAt')
    .startAfter(lastDocSnapshot)
    .limit(limit);

  return screamsRef;
}
```

When I add the 'desc' argument to this function like so:

```
export function fetchScreamsFromFirestore(limit, lastDocSnapshot = null) {
  let screamsRef = db
    .collection('screams')
    .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
    .startAfter(lastDocSnapshot)
    .limit(limit);

  return screamsRef;
}
```

It then returns nothing. Any thought on how I can fix this?

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what exactly is not working the way you expect.  You should indicate the data you're working with and spell out the steps you take to get there.  Right now, we can't see how you're getting and passing lastDocSnapshot, or what the query should return.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little late here but I think this might just be a syntax issue?

Try...

```
    export function fetchScreamsFromFirestore(limit, lastDocSnapshot = null) {
  let screamsRef = db
    .collection('screams')
    .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
    .startAfter(lastDocSnapshot)
    .limit(limit);

  return screamsRef;
}
```